# Loading URL result in SQL Server table with PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a PowerShell script that gives the latest SP and CU available of all the versions of SQL Server by directly querying over the web by using the below method and saving the output into an HTML file.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri $URI
```

I want the same result in a SQL Server table but I'm unable to do so. please help me understand how to achieve this.

Below is the complete code:

Note: You can directly execute this script.

## -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
# Script to display all SQL Server Service Packs per version available on microsoft technet

$URI = "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/latest-updates-for-microsoft-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15"
$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri $URI
# $WebResponse
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ------------------------------------------------- 
# Format the Output 
# -------------------------------------------------
 $content = $WebResponse.RawContent -replace "\s*`n", " " 
 $Tab=$content -match "<table(.*)</table>"
 $Output=$matches[0]
 while ($Output.Contains("  ")){
    $Output = $Output -replace "  "," "
 }
 $Output= $Output.replace('class="grid"','id="grid"').replace("<td> <strong>","<th>").replace("</strong> </td>","</th>")
$OutputFile=".\SQLServer-Latest-SP-CU.html"
 $PageTableHeader | out-file $OutputFile -encoding default
 out-file $OutputFile -encoding default -Append
 $Output | out-file $OutputFile -encoding default -Append
 out-file $OutputFile -encoding default -Append
 Write-Host "Output written to $OutputFile"
 start $OutputFile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your html is well-formed, you can use XML methods in T-SQL to parse and insert into a table. The example below take your existing $Output string with html and passes it as an XML parameter.

```
$sql = @"
CREATE TABLE dbo.SqlPatches(
      ProductVersion varchar(30)
    , LatestServicePack varchar(30)
    , LatestCumulativeUpdate varchar(30)
    , GeneralGuidance varchar(30)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.SqlPatches
SELECT 
      b.value('./td[1]','varchar(100)') AS ProductVersion
    , b.value('./td[2]','varchar(100)') AS LatestServicePack
    , b.value('./td[2]','varchar(100)') AS LatestCumulativeUpdate
    , b.value('./td[2]','varchar(100)') AS GeneralGuidance
FROM @SqlPatches.nodes('/table/tbody/tr') AS a(b);
"@

$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=SSPI")
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sql, $connection)
$command.Parameters.Add("@SqlPatches", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Xml).Value = $Output
$connection.Open()
[void]$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
$connection.Close()
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Excellent Dan! Thanks much.

Comment: @Manish, glad it helped. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.